# How can i display JavaScript function return in textbox?

Tags: javascript

I have this JavaScript code how can i display the return value in a text box or in a label?

```
  <script>
     function getSelectedProjectID() {
            var BalanceDue = @Model.BalanceDue;
            return {
                id: ProjectID
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: This isn't valid javascript, can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: `$("#labelId").val(getSelectedProjectID().id)`

Comment: @freedomn-m i have this `<label for="currency">Balance Due:</label>`?

Comment: @SuperStormer I enclose in the `<script></script>` that's how i have it

Comment: You probably want to adjust your tags. It has nothing to do with JQuery or C#.  You probably want to add ASP.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can assign your label an id

```
<label id="labelId"></label>
```

, and then just return function content to this label textConent:

```
 document.getElementById("labelId").textContent = getSelectedProjectID();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vanilla JS, you could do :

```
let labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label');
for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
if (labels[i].htmlFor == 'currency') {
     label.innerHTML = getSelectedProjectID().id;        
    }
}
```